# Repeat rows and iterate time python

Tags: python, pandas

I need help with this. I want to repeat the previous row and iterate time to one second before the next row based on a condition. That is, when the indicator >= 1, repeat previous row and iterate time to the next time as shown in the output. Below is my code.

The Input:

| b0 | b1 | time | Indicator |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 325 | 350 | 10:59:40 | 0 |
| 200 | 42333 | 10:59:45 | 1 |

This is what I was thinking...

Code:

To sort and filter the data

```py
   df_new = df #new dataframe
   new_index = 0 #to keep track of index in df_new inside the loop

 for i,row in df.iterrows():
    new_row = {}
    if (row['indicator'] > 1) and (i!=0):
        for column in df.columns:
            if column == 'time':
                new_row[column] = row[column] + datetime.timedelta(seconds=-1)
            else:
                new_row[column] = prev_row[column]
```

The problem I'm having is iterating the time. At the moment, it is only doing it for the second before the next timestamp.

The Output:

| b0 | b1 | time | Indicator |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 325 | 350 | 10:59:40 | 0 |
| 325 | 350 | 10:59:41 | 0 |
| 325 | 350 | 10:59:42 | 0 |
| 325 | 350 | 10:59:43 | 0 |
| 325 | 350 | 10:59:44 | 0 |
| 200 | 42333 | 10:59:45 | 1 |

Comment: if there are two consecutive rows with Indicator = 0 like this `[325,350,'10:59:40',0], [200,42333,'10:59:45',1], [300,1234,'10:59:52',0], [400,2345,'10:59:55',0], 
[500,3456,'10:59:58',1]`, do you want to repeat the b0 value of `300`?

Answer (score 1):

This was achieved by using several functions instead of loop processing. First, use `asfrq()` to fill in the holes at one-second intervals. The interval value = 0 in the created data frame and the interval value = 1 in the original data frame are concatenated and sorted into a time series.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

data = '''
b0 b1 time Indicator
325 350 10:59:40 0
200 42333 10:59:45 1
424 236 11:00:00 0
525 361 11:00:10 0
623 896 11:00:20 1
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)

df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df.set_index('time', inplace=True)
dfs = df.asfreq('1s', method='ffill')
dfs = pd.concat([dfs[dfs['Indicator'] == 0], df[df['Indicator'] == 1]], axis=0)
dfs.sort_values(by='time', ascending=True, inplace=True)

dfs
    b0  b1  Indicator
time            
2021-02-06 10:59:40     325     350     0
2021-02-06 10:59:41     325     350     0
2021-02-06 10:59:42     325     350     0
2021-02-06 10:59:43     325     350     0
2021-02-06 10:59:44     325     350     0
2021-02-06 10:59:45     200     42333   1
2021-02-06 11:00:00     424     236     0
2021-02-06 11:00:01     424     236     0
2021-02-06 11:00:02     424     236     0
2021-02-06 11:00:03     424     236     0
2021-02-06 11:00:04     424     236     0
2021-02-06 11:00:05     424     236     0
2021-02-06 11:00:06     424     236     0
2021-02-06 11:00:07     424     236     0
2021-02-06 11:00:08     424     236     0
2021-02-06 11:00:09     424     236     0
2021-02-06 11:00:10     525     361     0
2021-02-06 11:00:11     525     361     0
2021-02-06 11:00:12     525     361     0
2021-02-06 11:00:13     525     361     0
2021-02-06 11:00:14     525     361     0
2021-02-06 11:00:15     525     361     0
2021-02-06 11:00:16     525     361     0
2021-02-06 11:00:17     525     361     0
2021-02-06 11:00:18     525     361     0
2021-02-06 11:00:19     525     361     0
2021-02-06 11:00:20     623     896     1
```

Comment: Didnt realize asfreq was an option. Thx for sharing. upvoted

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it.

1. Step 1: convert `time` column to datetime data type

   `df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'],format='%H:%M:%S')`
2. Step 2: Get the time difference between next row and current row.
   Convert NaN to 0, and finally convert the value to integer.

   `df['time_diff'] = (df.time.shift(-1) - df.time).dt.seconds.fillna(0).astype(int)`
3. Step 3: Get the next row Indicator using shift (-1). Replacing NaN
   with 0

   `df['next_ind'] = df.Indicator.shift(-1).fillna(0).astype(int)`
4. Step 4: If current row Indicator is >=1, ignore the row by setting
   time_diff to 1. We will NOT repeat this row. Value is set to 1.

   `df.loc[df.Indicator >= 1, 'time_diff'] = 1`
5. Step 5: Similarly check if current row is 0 and next row is also 0.
   If so, we will also need to ignore this row. We will NOT repeat this
   row. Value is set to 1

   `df.loc[(df.Indicator == 0) & (df.next_ind == 0), 'time_diff'] = 1`
6. Step 6: All values in time_diff will have a 1 or the time difference
   between rows with 0 and next row with >=1. This will be used as a
   value to repeat the rows. Create a list so we can explode.

   `df['time'] = df.apply(lambda x: list(pd.date_range(x['time'], periods=x['time_diff'], freq=pd.DateOffset(seconds=1))),axis=1)`
7. Step 7: Now explode the dataframe on column time as it contains
   lists.

   `df = df.explode('time')`
8. Step 8: Print the final dataframe for desired results

Putting all this together, the code is as shown below.

```
c = ['b0','b1','time','Indicator']
d = [[325,350,'10:59:40',0],
     [200,42333,'10:59:45',1],
     [300,1234,'10:59:52',0],
     [400,2345,'10:59:55',0],
     [500,3456,'10:59:58',1],
     [600,4567,'11:00:03',2]]
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(d,columns=c)
print (df)
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'],format='%H:%M:%S')

df['time_diff'] = (df.time.shift(-1) - df.time).dt.seconds.fillna(0).astype(int)
df['next_ind'] = df.Indicator.shift(-1).fillna(0).astype(int)

df.loc[df.Indicator >= 1, 'time_diff'] = 1
df.loc[(df.Indicator == 0) & (df.next_ind == 0), 'time_diff'] = 1

df['time'] = df.apply(lambda x: list(pd.date_range(x['time'], periods=x['time_diff'], freq=pd.DateOffset(seconds=1))),axis=1)
df = df.explode('time')
df.drop(columns=['time_diff','next_ind'],inplace=True)
print (df)
```

Output of this will be:

Original DataFrame:

```
    b0     b1      time  Indicator
0  325    350  10:59:40          0
1  200  42333  10:59:45          1
2  300   1234  10:59:52          0
3  400   2345  10:59:55          0
4  500   3456  10:59:58          1
5  600   4567  11:00:03          2
```

Updated DataFrame:

```
    b0     b1                time  Indicator
0  325    350 1900-01-01 10:59:40          0
0  325    350 1900-01-01 10:59:41          0
0  325    350 1900-01-01 10:59:42          0
0  325    350 1900-01-01 10:59:43          0
0  325    350 1900-01-01 10:59:44          0
1  200  42333 1900-01-01 10:59:45          1
2  300   1234 1900-01-01 10:59:52          0
3  400   2345 1900-01-01 10:59:55          0
3  400   2345 1900-01-01 10:59:56          0
3  400   2345 1900-01-01 10:59:57          0
4  500   3456 1900-01-01 10:59:58          1
5  600   4567 1900-01-01 11:00:03          2
```

Comment: Thanks, question though, how would we do it if we had to read the data from a csv file and it had far more rows than stated?

Comment: just read the csv file as is. then do from step 1 onwards. The base is the dataframe. If you were to read from a csv_file, you would have `df = pd.read_csv ('file_name.csv')` and it would create all the columns. We are only interested in these columns. All others will NOT be impacted.

Comment: Okay thanks. Also,  I noticed your code repeats the rows only when indicator is 1. What if we want to do it when indicator is 1 and greater than 1. So basically we're repeating the previous row when the indicator is 1 or greater

Comment: It works for any value. Replace `[200,42333,'10:59:45',3],` to 3 as i did here and see if it works. For what condition does it NOT work? It works for me when i change it to 3

Comment: Yes it does. I had a typo in the code. Thanks!

Comment: Does it address all the scenarios? If it solves all the usecases, then feel free to mark this as the answer and upvote

Comment: Yes it does. Thanks